# What is the preferred way to reference own material?

Tags: support, answers

When I write something that could be clarified or improved by a reference or a quote from an earlier post of mine, here or elsewhere, what is the preferred way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First, take a step back

- If you want to copy content from an earlier answer, maybe the question should be closed as a duplicate.
- If it is not a duplicate, are you sure that the content is really helpful to the asker, and not just remotely related (in which case a comment with a link would suffice)? We prefer quality over quantity.

#### Be clear that it is not original content

Provide a link, and put the relevant text in a quote.

> Like so. ([ref](http://.))

#### Don't copy too much

Only quote the most important part, and provide a link so that interested readers may click through. Don't clutter your new post with only semi-related stuff.